# jQuery testing for CSS value is not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have a checkbox that I show/hide based on a drop down selection on the page.

```
$("#Units").change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == "D") {
    $('#chkSkipSatSun').css('display', 'inline'); 
  } else {
    $('#chkSkipSatSun').css('display', 'none'); 
  }
});
```

On page load, the checkbox is hidden. I turn it on using the drop down and submit the page and this test keeps failing:

```
if ($('#chkSatSun').css('display') == 'inline') {
  alert('in');
}
```

I look at the HTML in the browser and the display is definitely set to inline but this test keeps failing. How can I get this test to work and see the CSS value of inline in the DOM?

Comment: shouldn't this `#chkSatSun` be `#chkSkipSatSun`

Comment: `.show()`,  `.hide()` and `.is(':visible')` are semantically better (will make more sense when you read it) then testing/setting css values. Also it's best practice to [use ===](http://www.impressivewebs.com/why-use-triple-equals-javascipt/) to compare. It will help to maintain dataType integrity throughout your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('#chkSatSun')` and `$('#chkSkipSatSun')` are different things.

Comment: Thanks Grant! I call that a blindness moment. :)